# Syntax error while writing pip in terminal

Tags: scipy, pip, python-2.x, python-2.6

I'm working with Python 2.6.6. Everything was working fine until I wrote

```
pip install --upgrade --user pip
```

Then the terminal say:

```
 Successfully installed pip-7.1.0
```

After I tried to install SciPy with:

```
 pip install -U scipy
```

But now I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==7.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in main
from pip._internal.utils.entrypoints import _wrapper
File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", 
line 3, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.main import main
File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in 
<module>
from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", 
line 9, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 
7, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
File "/home/mauricio/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 
104 binary_only = FormatControl(set(), {':all:'})
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any recommendations to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
easy_install-2.6 --upgrade 'setuptools<37' 'pip<10'
```

If it doesn't work install `pip` from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/get-pip.py :

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py # or wget -O
python2.6 get-pip.py
```